# Deeplinking in React Native with Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to use Deeplinking in React Native using navigation v5. I am following official [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links#marking-params-as-optional).

But there seems to be an issue working with the config structure mentioned in the official docs.

`config` looks like this

```
  const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      screens: {
        NPM: {
          screen: {
            CameraNPM: {
              path: 'CameraNPM/:cameraview',
              params: {cameraview: 3},
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    ImagePicker: {
      path: 'ImagePicker/:id',
      params: {
        id: 0,
      },
      parse: {
        id: (id: string) => `user-${id}`,
      },
      stringify: {
        id: (id: string) => id.replace(/^user-/, ''),
      },
    },
    Geolocation: 'Geolocation',
    NotFound: '*', //error!
  },
};
```

and `linking`

```
  const linking = {
  prefixes: ['url://homescreen://', 'homescreen://'],
  config: {config},
};
```

this structure works fine but typescript complains of not adding the `screens` tag in the `linking` variable. Furthermore, `NotFound: '*"` (unmatched route) causes a crash if added with above structure.

If I prefix `config: {config}` with `screens`  (`screens{config: {config}}`) then typescript stops complaining and unmatched route does not cause any crash but nested navigation does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this:

```js
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['url://homescreen://', 'homescreen://'],
    config: { config } 
}
```

with

```js
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['url://homescreen://', 'homescreen://'],
    config: config 
}
```

or even shorter:

```js
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['url://homescreen://', 'homescreen://'],
    config
}
```

The first option (the one you're using) will result in a variable with the following structure:

```js
{
    prefixes: Array<string>,
    config: {
        config: {
            // Your actual config
        }
    }
}
```

because you're passing it like this: `config: { config }` instead of `config: config` or simply `config`. You may have gotten confused trying to do `config: { ...config }` which would work as intended but it unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Yanick. With this nested navigator's `CameraNPM` is not being resolved. Nothing happen when I do this `npx uri-scheme open homescreen://Home/NPM/CameraNPM?cameraview=45 --android`

Comment: That's because you haven't defined any path for `Home` or `NPM`. Simply opening `homescreen://CameraNPM?cameraView=45` should work. You should also rename the `screen` key to `screens` inside the `NPM` config.

Comment: thanks for the reply. `homescreen://NPM/CameraNPM?cameraview=45` worked for me.